# Start a process on Azure remotely

Tags: c#, windows, azure

I would like to be able to start a number of concurrent processes (command line programs) on Azure remotely. I need to be able to make a call from a C# program to start these processes off. What would be the best approach to this?

1. Set up an Azure VM with IIS
2. Install the various .exes that I want to run.
3. Write and install a web service on the box that can take parameters and start the processes on the server.

Is there an easier way to do this using Azure though? I am not familiar with Azure VMs or worker roles etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Do they absolutely have to be command-line programs? If there's possibility to host classes of the exes in services, there are simple ways to achieve what you're asking.

Comment: No, if I could deploy the exes as classes in a webservice that would be easier for me. Do you have any links to show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of Azure Worker Roles and Windows Azure Storage for that purpose. What you could do is either package the executables along with the worker role package so that they are always available in your role or you could save them in blob storage so that you can download on demand into your worker role. From your calling application, you can put messages in a queue which will be constantly polled by your worker role. The message will contain enough information (for example exe to invoke etc.). Once the message is received, the worker role will execute the executable.

Hope this helps.